# Fixed sidebar next to a centered div

Tags: css, sidebar

I have a centered div (which is the main content of the page) with the property `margin: 0 auto`, and now I want a sidebar fixed next to it but I don't understand how to achieve it. I can do it with `left: 30%` or something like that, but that's not responsive.

This is what I have at the moment:

https://jsfiddle.net/yp74vo70/

Comment: will the width of the center div be 100px all the time?

Comment: No @SahilDhir in the real case it's going to be 800 width, but I think it's the same

Comment: Cool then go with the calc(50% + centerdiv/2) answer as given by akrej

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use: `left: calc(50% + 50px);`

```css
div.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: dashed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 2000px;
}

div.sidebar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: dotted;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: calc(50% + 50px);
    width: calc( (100% - 100px) / 2 );
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    RIGHT SIDEBAR
  </div>
  <div class="centered">
    CENTERED
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbjdn1k0/1/)

Comment: This is the best approach at the moment, but there is a moment that the sidebar is going off the screen...

Comment: You can use `width: calc( (100% - 100px) / 2 );` to make the width of the sidebar responsive. See updated answer

Comment: That's it, perfect. Thanks!